# Configure PHP to use a proxy?

Tags: php, configuration, proxy

Using PHP 5.2.6 and need to configure it to use our forward proxy (which requires authentication be set) so that the PHP scripts can connect to the internet correctly.

I see that PHP.INI in the 4 version had a pfpro.proxyaddress option but that is no longer available - so what has replaced it?

Answer (score 4):

you can use curl for handling your http retrievals.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://whatever.com/something/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://10.14.10.1:3128");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user:pass");
```

more info [here](https://www.php.net/curl)

Comment: CURLOPT_PROXY with ip:port and a separate CURLOPT_PROXYPORT with the same port sounds unneccesary

Comment: @Karsten - yes. you're right.

Comment: -1: That is code related - I am looking for a configuration related method as in v4 that can be set so all requests are proxied.

Comment: @Robert MacLean - it seems what you ask for might be still not implemented - take a look at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29280 ; they also discuss kind-of-workaround with auto-append and changing settings of default context, but it's a hack